# SpringBatch accessing Line Number in Item processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am reading a CSV file with thousands of records, processing it and saving records in DB, I am doing validations in ItemPreocessor and writing errors to a file, I need to write line number of the record with the errors as below

LineNumber  field      error
4           age       negative
5           type      Invalid
5           postcode  Invalid

How can I get hold of Line number in ItemProcessor, any help is much appreciated.There is no unique identifier in file so showing the line number is mandatory, it is coming from external source.

Thanks,
GAR

Comment: Does the input CSV contain a line number column? It is hard to conclude an exact answer with what you need with the provided information. Can you please provide a sample input CSV and how you construct the error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check all the annotation available and create a flow that fit your requirements (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/annotation/package-summary.html).
For example the following processor will init the lineNumber to 0 before the chunk proccess the data. However if the file contains more than the chunk size, you should store the number of chunk that have been executed in the execution context and then add to the lineNumber.

```
public class RecordProcessors implements ItemProcessor<Record , List<Record >> {
  private int lineNumber;
  @BeforeChunk
  public void init() {

    lineNumber = 0;
  }

  @Override
  public List<Record> process(Record record) {

    // do validation
    record.setLineNumber(lineNumber)
    return record;
  }
}
```